# Getting missing comma error when using Pivot function on a table

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am creating a simple pivot but I get the ORA-00917: missing comma error on the line where the pivot function exists (third line). Please help.

Not sure what else to try as the syntax seems to be correct as I am new to the pivot function.

```
SELECT venue, notional
FROM ABC
pivot (sum(notional) FOR (venue) IN ('A' as A1 , 'B' as B1));
```

The expected result would be A1 and B1 showing their respective notionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you miss the sub-query before PIVOT function -

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT venue, notional
      FROM ABC
     )
PIVOT (
        SUM(notional) FOR (venue) IN ('A' as A1 , 'B' as B1)
      );
```

Comment: Another question related to this though. Can we have more than one IN clause when doing a pivot e.g.let's say I want to do this
```
PIVOT (
        SUM(notional) FOR (venue) IN ('A' as A1 , 'B' as B1) AND (type) IN ('Prime'));
````
Type being another column that I would like to include in the pivot

Comment: You have to include another whole PIVOT clause for that.

Comment: ````````````````
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT venue, type_, notional
      FROM ABC
     )
PIVOT (
        SUM(notional) FOR (venue) IN ('A' as A1 , 'B' as B1)
      )
PIVOT (
        SUM(notional) FOR (type_) IN ('Prime')
      );
``````````````````````````
tried this but getting invalid identifier error for notional

Comment: I guess you can post the new question instead with your sample data and your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a sub-query. The columns `venue` and `notional` in the `ABC` table have been pivoted and no longer exist in the output result set so the `SELECT` clause will not find those columns.

Instead `SELECT` the `a1` and `b1` columns you have pivoted:

**Test Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE abc ( id, venue, notional ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'B', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'B', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B', 3 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT id, a1, b1      -- you can't use venue or notional here as they've been pivoted.
FROM ABC
pivot (sum(notional) FOR (venue) IN ('A' as A1 , 'B' as B1));
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID |   A1 | B1
> -: | ---: | -:
>  1 |    6 |  3
>  2 | null |  3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e0f7763a5a06b8adba0c5b6b37eb697d)*